# Preferred maximum indentation in Python?

Tags: python

I'm reading [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and notice that it does not say anything on maximum levels of indentation. Of course the 79 character limit puts a limit to levels of indentation, but **is there a recommended maximum indentation level in Python?** What's your take on this? Do you have company level policies?

As an example from somewhere else, Linus Torvals states in [the Linux kernel Style Guide](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) that

> [...] The answer to that is that if you need more than 3 levels of
>   indentation, you're screwed anyway, and should fix your program.

Comment: Have a look at the kernel sources – it's not hard to find lines written by Linus that use more than three levels of indentation.  In Python, you certainly need more than three levels sometimes.  Method bodies already have two levels, so restricting yourself to three levels would give you only a single level inside a method.

Comment: `flat is better than nested` - You should just refactor until your code is flat enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Readability *is* the most important thing here. 4 or 5 levels of indentation over a dozen lines isn't really as much of a problem to read as 3 levels in a function that runs over 4 or 5 pages/screens

If you are wondering if you have too much indentation, you probably do. Can you refactor your code to use some functions? list/dict/set comprehensions? Maybe look at itertools to see if something there can help? ...

Answer (score 6):

I have hit a hard indentation limit while meta-programming (writing code that writes code), and it is 100. In CPython 2.7.8, this is what is thrown upon import:

```
IndentationError: too many levels of indentation
```

So, to your actual question, under any context or policy, the preferred limit must be under 100! :)

Comment: Since the code was generated mainly for performance, there are cases where you'd benefit from a huge if tree. The code was not meant to be manually editable or understandable by itself! I got around the limit by restructuring parts of the decision tree to use a flatter-yet-less-performant format: while 1: if condition: action break

Comment: This got me curious so I wrote this just to see for myself.
```python
def build_indent_string(max_iter=10):
    iter_count = 0
    indented_string = 'def f():\n\tpass'
    while iter_count < max_iter:
        indented_string = 'def f():\n\t'+indented_string.replace('\n','\n\t')+'\n\tpass'
        yield indented_string
        iter_count += 1

try:
    for nested_funcs in build_indent_string(n=1000):
        exec(nested_funcs)
finally:
    print(max([line.count('\t') for line in nested_funcs.split('\n')]))
```
returns `100` just as you said. (not that I doubted)

Comment: That was the first time I put a code block into a comment. Won't be doing that again! so ugly.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider Linus Torvalds's 3-levels-of-indentation-rule valid as long as you're dealing with a procedural paradigm (and not always anyway, since *almost nothing is always valid*).

Python, unlike C, offers OOP, which adds at least one more level of indentation, so you often might need 3-4 levels of indentation, if not more.

Answer (score 2):

As it's style, personal preference plays a part, but 3-4 is as far as you should be going.

However, readability is king so ideally get someone else to look over your code and tell you if it's hard to follow.

Like a lot of Python "rules", bend them if you can justify it.

Answer (score 0):

The max indent level is 100 only, you could also check in github repo of CPython.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Parser/tokenizer.h